# Oracle database transaction

Tags: oracle, transactions

I have a question about transactional queries on oracle Db(or other RDBMS).
I have for instance 3 tables in my transactionnal script. What happen if I call begin transaction on each of three tables and at the end I command commit also on each table?
Is it necessary to do that?

Comment: It's neither necessary nor even possible. You don't "begin transaction" on a table, you just begin a transaction.

Comment: Let me add something. My transaction is call on a php code with an object mapped to a table of my db like PDO

Comment: Then you need to look at the docs for whatever framework you're using in PHP to know what it does.